# Replace quote sign in JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I got following code snippet, it's pretty simple,

```js
var b = "'aa','bb'";

console.log(b.replace("'", ""));
// result is "aa','bb'"
```

I want replace all **single quote** signs with **blank**. So my expected output should be `"aa,bb"`, but the actual output is `"aa','bb'"` neither run this code snippet in Node nor browser. Seems only the first single quote sign has been replaced.
I already got a workaround to resolve this problem by replace with regex. What I wanna know
is what happened to ***replace*** function here? I cannot figure this out.

Comment: I found the answer from MDN, this is the JavaScript default behavior, which is different from most languages I know.

Answer (score 1):

Try using RegEx specifying the [*global*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) flag (`g`) that ***matches the pattern multiple times***. Please also note that, as `replace()` does not modify the original string you have to reassign the modified value to the variable:

```js
var b = "'aa','bb'";
b = b.replace(/'/g, "");
console.log(b);
```